# How to replicate the following Spyder behavior in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ipython, spyder

I'm new to coding Python in VSCode. Previously I used Spyder but decided to move to VSCode as the project management seems better in it (I could easily switch to other files/folders by clicking on the path, just like in PyCharm). But I really need this one workflow which I still have not managed to do it in VSCode.

1. write some codes like Selenium.
2. Click run (F5)
3. The selenium browser opens up.
4. I could use the Ipython terminal to access the code interactively (find the element in the browser etc) and send new command.

I would like to have this workflow in VSCode. Im also quite overwhelmed by the difference in these 2 IDEs, for example, in VSCode, you have integrated terminal, a debugging console and an output tab, while im used to have only one-for-all Ipython tab.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I figured out what I need. Basically I just need to right click on the python file that I want to run on the side bar. Then I have to select 'run current file in interactive window'. The only difference is on the Ipython console, I have to use shift+Enter to send my input instead of just clicking enter. But its not a big deal.